# What's the difference with opencv, opencv-python, and libopencv?

Tags: python, opencv, ubuntu-14.04

I'm new to `opencv` and using `ubuntu 14.04`, I'm confused of the difference with `opencv`, `opencv-python`, and `libopencv`, as I have `libopencv` and `opencv-python` installed in my system, but I there is no `cv` interface accessible, so I have to install `opencv` which is much harder than `opencv-python` and `libopencv`.

Comment: Python's opencv interface exists as `cv2`

Comment: did you get what you wanted? Share your thoughts too!!

Answer (score 12):

I would like to add to Andika's answer.

1. [OpenCV](http://opencv.org/about.html) is computer vision a library written using highly optimized C/C++ code. It makes use of multiprocessing in the background. It has a collection of a large number of algorithms tested and verifiend by the developers. The best thing about this is it's FREE under the BSD license.
2. [libopencv](https://packages.debian.org/sid/libopencv-dev) is only a metapackage. These packages do not contain actual software, they simply depend on other packages to be installed. So libopencv is a metapackage which simply references one or more related packages which are loosely grouped together. It is dedicated for installing OpenCV in Ubuntu and Debian OS.
3. [opencv-python](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/opencv-python) is the OpenCV library available as a wrapper with bindings for python. The link also shows how to install OpenCV in Ubuntu OS.

Comment: hi @Jeru, for a new conda environment, if I'd like to use opencv in my python jupyter notebook. Do I need to install the 3 libraries, or I just need to install Python-PpenCV? thanks

Comment: also, could you please alter the Python-OpenCV to its correct name: opencv-python ? As a new starter , I found it's so confusing to have so many different but similar xxx-cv, cv-xxx.

Comment: @Franva you can go with opencv-python

Answer (score 4):

libopencv is the debian/ubuntu package while python-opencv is the python wrapper and can be accessed using cv2 interface like COLDSPEED mentioned