# Which components do what when using Python with OpenCV?

Tags: python, opencv

I'm quite puzzled about what to use or install, because there are a plethora of components old and new, and the relationship between them is quite unclear to me.

There is [OpenCV](https://opencv.org), the C++ library that does the heavy lifting.

Then there are various packages that provide Python support, including:

- [opencv-python](https://pypi.org/project/opencv-python/) - Python packages for OpenCV; also installs OpenCV itself. Available with `import cv2`.
- [pyopencv](https://pypi.org/project/pyopencv/) - a very old library.
- [python-opencv](https://packages.debian.org/stretch/python-opencv) - a Debian package.
- [libopencv](https://packages.debian.org/stretch/libopencv-dev), described in [another question here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45450706/whats-the-difference-with-opencv-python-opencv-and-libopencv) as "only a metapackage", but its purpose remains unclear to me.

Possibly I have missed some...

For a modern Python 3 project, which of these components should be used?

### Using `import cv`

I am trying to use OpenCV with a Django project, that expects to find the library with `import cv`.

That recommends installing `python-opencv`. It also mentions `pyopencv` which seems odd, given how old the latter is.

What package *does* make a `cv` module available?

### System vs Python packages

It looks like `python-opencv` is a *system-level package* that also installs Python modules, whereas `opencv-python` is a *Python package* that also installs system-level modules.

Is that correct? In which case, am I right in thinking that one would install both system and Python libraries using one of these but not both?

Answer (score 1):

in opencv3 the old cv or cv2.cv api was removed, to use opencv correctly in python is enough with import cv2.

another package would be opencv-contrib-python